# Mac multiple dylibs

Tags: macos, qt, dylib

I know this question is not specific to crypto++.  But I compiled crypto++ on a Mac OS X using Qt.  After building I see 4 files with the dylib extention:

```
libcryptopp.1.0.0.dylib
libcryptopp.1.0.dylib
libcryptopp.1.dylib
libcryptopp.dylib
```

What is the difference between them? Which one is actually used to compile against my application?

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, there's just one actual dylib (libcryptopp.1.0.0.dylib) and 3 links to that one. These give you the version info for the library.

If you want to link to a specific version you can specify that, else if you always expect your app to work with the latest version, you can point to libcryptopp.dylib.

Comment: Thanks makes since now.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple files exist in case your application needs to link to a specific version of it. Of course, you have just one version of the library, so it doesn't seem helpful, but consider these on my system:

- libnetsnmp.15.1.2.dylib
- libnetsnmp.15.dylib
- libnetsnmp.25.dylib
- libnetsnmp.5.2.1.dylib
- libnetsnmp.5.dylib
- libnetsnmp.dylib

Only .25, .15.1.2 and .5.2.1 are actual files, the rest are symbolic links for either. In your case, they're probably all symlinks except 1.0.0, so you case use either.

Comment: Yup your right.  I understand the version but weird that it creates multiple for the same buid.  But in either case that cleared it all up for me thanks

Comment: There is just one real file, all the others are links to that one file.

Comment: On a mac would their also be a link file?  Like a libcryptopp.a that i would link to -lcryptopp?  I cant seem to find one after i created a build

Comment: @adviner, a .a file is a static library. A .dylib file is a dynamic library (equivalent to .so in the Linux world and .dll in the Windows world). The dylib needs to be in one of the folders the linker will look for.